# Mysql pdo - не информативный errorInfo

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, pdo

Выполняю запрос:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM 'users' ";
$stmt = con_pdo()->prepare("$sql");
```

Получаю результаты:

```
$rezult = $stmt->fetchAll; 
print_r($rezult);
```

Страница чистая, в таблице 3 записи. Пытаюсь выявить ошибки:

```
print_r(con()->errorInfo());
```

Ответ:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 00000
    [1] => 
    [2] => 
)
```

Вывожу

```
print_r($stmt);


PDOStatement Object
(
    [queryString] => SELECT * FROM 'users' 
)
```

Что за магия?

Comment: похоже, что ошибки нет. Может записи не видно из за каких нибудь недопустимых символов при выводе в html, например `<`

Comment: Код 00000 означает что ошибок __нет__

Comment: А проблема ваша в кавычках.

Comment: Откуда взяться ошибке у запроса, который ещё никто не выполнял? Я не вижу у вас никакого execute. Ну и fetchAll - метод, а не свойство. И здесь должен быть по крайней мере E_NOTICE. То есть большой вопрос к конфигурации вывода ошибок.

Comment: Больше ошибок богу ошибок.